# how to set value in other column while using case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I creating different labels for my column, depending on various conditions. And it looks like this:

```
, CASE
    WHEN phone like '%555%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS first_label

, CASE
    WHEN phone like '%888%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS second_label
```

But also i need to name this new lable in new column like `lable name = 'first_label'` for each row. So how can i do it whithout copying that blocks again?
My result:

```
SELECT 
, phone    
, CASE
    WHEN phone like '%555%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS first_label
, CASE
    WHEN phone like '%888%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS second_label
, 'lable_name' as lable_name

FROM mytable
```

expected output:

| phone | first_label | second_label | lable_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 75 71 1 | 1 | 0 | first_label |
| 888 94 18 3 | 0 | 1 | second_label |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to repeat the expressions again, simply select from your query result. E.g.:

```
WITH labeled AS
(
  SELECT 
    phone, 
    CASE WHEN phone like '%555%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_label,
    CASE WHEN phone like '%888%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS second_label
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT
  phone,
  first_label,
  second_label,
  CASE
    WHEN first_label = 1 AND second_label = 1 THEN 'both labels'
    WHEN first_label = 1 AND second_label = 0 THEN 'first_label'
    WHEN first_label = 0 AND second_label = 1 THEN 'second_label'
    ELSE                                           'no label'
  END AS label_names
FROM labeled;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/zwDO1N1Q